# how to filter the records in object array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Set of object array Called Datasource**

```
{"A":[{"accountSoftwareRegUid":1792690,"accountUid":646882,"registrationIdOrOrderItemID":"Not Required For Eval JZ399AAE","registrationType":"RegistrationId",},{"accountSoftwareRegUid":1792691,"accountUid":646882,"registrationIdOrOrderItemID":"Not Required For Eval JZ400AAE","registrationType":"RegistrationId",},{"accountSoftwareRegUid":1792691,"accountUid":646882,"registrationIdOrOrderItemID":"Not Required For Eval JZ400AAE","registrationType":"RegistrationId",},],"B":[{"accountSoftwareRegUid":832633,"accountUid":719261,"registrationIdOrOrderItemID":"1168738","registrationType":"order","passPhrase":"AR0005493ARB",},{"accountSoftwareRegUid":832675,"accountUid":719261,"registrationIdOrOrderItemID":"1168739","registrationType":"order","passPhrase":"AR0005493ARB",},],"C":[{"accountSoftwareRegUid":651923,"accountUid":646882,"registrationIdOrOrderItemID":"1384120","registrationType":"order","passPhrase":null,"organisationName":"flyasiana",},{"accountSoftwareRegUid":637694,"accountUid":646882,"registrationIdOrOrderItemID":"1116033","registrationType":"order","passPhrase":null,"organisationName":"korea Correctional Service",},],}
```

and I have another set of array-like

```
accountSoftwareRegUid[1792690,832633]
```

I Need output looks like

```
{"A":[{"accountSoftwareRegUid":1792690,"accountUid":646882,"registrationIdOrOrderItemID":"Not Required For Eval JZ399AAE","registrationType":"RegistrationId",},],"B":[{"accountSoftwareRegUid":832633,"accountUid":719261,"registrationIdOrOrderItemID":"1168738","registrationType":"order","passPhrase":"AR0005493ARB",},],}
```

Comment: Actually, I need to filter the records based on the condition(accountSoftwareRegUid)So that the output A has been 1 record and B has one record

Comment: Are you incapable of writing your own code? Do you have anything that shows the effort you have made to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const dataSource = {
  "A": [{
    "accountSoftwareRegUid": 1792690,
    "accountUid": 646882,
    "registrationIdOrOrderItemID": "Not Required For Eval JZ399AAE",
    "registrationType": "RegistrationId",
  }, {
    "accountSoftwareRegUid": 1792691,
    "accountUid": 646882,
    "registrationIdOrOrderItemID": "Not Required For Eval JZ400AAE",
    "registrationType": "RegistrationId",
  }, {
    "accountSoftwareRegUid": 1792691,
    "accountUid": 646882,
    "registrationIdOrOrderItemID": "Not Required For Eval JZ400AAE",
    "registrationType": "RegistrationId",
  }, ],
  "B": [{
    "accountSoftwareRegUid": 832633,
    "accountUid": 719261,
    "registrationIdOrOrderItemID": "1168738",
    "registrationType": "order",
    "passPhrase": "AR0005493ARB",
  }, {
    "accountSoftwareRegUid": 832675,
    "accountUid": 719261,
    "registrationIdOrOrderItemID": "1168739",
    "registrationType": "order",
    "passPhrase": "AR0005493ARB",
  }, ],
  "C": [{
    "accountSoftwareRegUid": 651923,
    "accountUid": 646882,
    "registrationIdOrOrderItemID": "1384120",
    "registrationType": "order",
    "passPhrase": null,
    "organisationName": "flyasiana",
  }, {
    "accountSoftwareRegUid": 637694,
    "accountUid": 646882,
    "registrationIdOrOrderItemID": "1116033",
    "registrationType": "order",
    "passPhrase": null,
    "organisationName": "korea Correctional Service",
  }, ],
};

const accountSoftwareRegUid = [1792690, 832633];

const result = {};

function getRecords(dataSource, accountSoftwareRegUid){
  Object.keys(dataSource).forEach((key) => {
    dataSource[key].forEach((record) => {
      if(accountSoftwareRegUid.includes(record.accountSoftwareRegUid)){
        if(result[key]){ // if result with the key exists the push it
          result[key].push(record);
        }else{  // else create a new key
          result[key] = [record];
        }
      }
    })
  })
  return result;
}

console.log(getRecords(dataSource, accountSoftwareRegUid));
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to filter?

```
const r = {
  model: {
    // This says keep the elements of datasource that have a Uid that appears in the other set
    A: datasource.model.A.filter(data => accountSoftwareRegUid.some(id => data.accountSoftwareRegUid === id)),
  },
}
```